# ES6 access exported 'default' instance from same file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export

I was wondering, when you export some data using the ES6 keyword `export` like so :

```
export default {
  data: "Hello !"
}
```

How can you then from the same file, access that exact same exported data ?

EDIT: Of course, without declaring it before exporting the variable...

Comment: Please provide more specifics. Bear in mind that updating the values of exports has different semantics depending on the format your transpiler is targeting. For example, CommonJS translations are lossy and in different ways between TypeScript and Babel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you structure your file like that, you cannot.

Usually, you define functions and data that you want to expose *before* the export statement, and then reference them when you build the exported object/function.

Bad way:

```
export default {
    data: 'Hello!',
    myFn: function (str) {
        console.log(str);
    }
}
```

Good way:

```
var data = 'Hello!';

var myFn = function (str) {
    console.log(str);
};

// code that uses data and myFn

// shorthand for { data: data, myFn: myFn }
export default { data, myFn };
```

Comment: Yep, you are right. But in some cases I need to access the exact same instance. For example, if I create an object and then `export` it. I will be able to access it and modify it, but it wont affect the exported instance that will be used in another file with an `import`. Tell me if I'm not clear.

Comment: You seem to be saying two different things. If you need to access the *exact same instance* then modifying it will certainly affect it in other files that have imported it. If you want to modify it *without modifying* imported instances in other files, that's another thing. Which are you looking for?

Comment: Actually I thought the instance was different, but I just made a stupid mistake veryfing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
export const data = 'hello';
```

Comment: This functionality is not the same as what OP posted. Your export doesn't have a default, which would break any code relying on a default export in OP's app.

Comment: What would be the point of such code? I'm not assuming that any consumers exist and need not be broken.

Answer (score 2):

For my similar use case -- I wanted easy access to everything the ES6 module exported from within the same module just for debugging purposes. So:

```
export const data = 'hi'
export const someFunc = () => `important data: ${data}`
export default someFunc()
export const funcToDebug() => {
    console.log(`what's going on here? ${myModule.exports.default}`)
}
var myModule = module
```

Comment: Nodejs throws at the last line. ReferenceError: module is not defined

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I just tried this in node and got a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`, but module is defined when I open the node REPL. (I forget how to get node to use import and export instead of require. I haven't been programming in JS for a bit.)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access internally the functions that you export, you should define them outside of the export statement. Like so:

```
const data = 'Hello !';

const someFunc = () => {
  return data + ' Goodbye!'
}

export default {
  data,
  someFunc
}
```

Now the variables and functions can reference each other without being "stuck" inside the export function. For example the following will NOT work:

```
// WRONG!
export default {
  data: 'Hello !',
  someFunc: () => {
    return data + ' Goodbye!';
  }
}
```

Comment: How so? It answers OP's question, which is to say _you can't_ unless you change how you're exporting.

Comment: Yes but it appears the op is misunderstanding default exports. It is using them in a counter-intuitive way. Default exports are one of the most misunderstood concepts in JavaScript

Comment: As I commented in Matt's answer, of course I know that I can declare objects and functions in that manner, and export them after, so I am able to access them. But what I am saying is that the instance being exported, and the instance being declared above is different. I needed it to be the same instance, for example I need to set something in the object, but it does'nt affect the exported instance being imported somewhere else.

Comment: In that case you may want to use a function closure. Put all your variables inside the function and export it's result, which will be an object.

Comment: @jaybee `return this.data + ' Goodbye!';` is perfectly fine